# Whenever I type "$effect [pokemon type]", the Discord bot doesn't react

Tags: discord.js, bots

The code is here: (file directory: bot > commands > pokemon)

```
module.exports = {
      name: 'effect',
      description: 'information on effects from pokke!'
      execute(message, args, Discord){
          const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#FFB8B8')
          .setTitle('Effect')
          .setDescription('This is what Pokke could easily lose and win against!')
            client.on('message', message =>{
                if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length)split(/ +/);
            const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

            if(commands === 'fairy'){
                message.channel.send('Fairies in particular are very cute...but they are weak against poison and steel which blows. At least they are Strong against fight, dragon and dark. Hmph...');
            }

            else if(commands === 'steel'){
                message.channel.send('Oh, these guys... well, they are Weak against fire, fight and ground. But strong against ice, rock and fairy.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'dark'){
                message.channel.send('They are pretty much Weak against fight, bug and fairy and trong against psychic and ghost.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'dragon'){
                message.channel.send('Weak against ice, dragon and fairy. Strong against dragon.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'ghost'){
                message.channel.send('These guys are pretty cool...um, they are weak against ghost and dark but also strong against psychic and ghost.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'rock'){
                message.channel.send('Rock, paper, scissors, shoot! Oh...wrong game. These Pokke are weak against water, grass, fight, ground and steel. They like taking on fire, ice, flying and bug, though.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'bug'){
                message.channel.send('These guys do not like fire, flying and rock. Strong againdt grass, psychic and dar.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'psychic'){
                message.channel.send('Psychics are weak against bug, ghost and dark. Strong against fight and poison, however. Neat.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'flying'){
                message.channel.send('These bird-like creatures love taking on grass, fight and bug types. But...they do not really stand a chance against rock, ice and elecric.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'ground'){
                message.channel.send('Hm...oh, yeah! These guys specialize in fighting fire, electric poison, rock and steel. They hate ice, grass and water though.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'poison'){
                message.channel.send('These poisonous fiends love defeating grass and fairies. However, psychic and ground can take them out.');

            }

            else if(commands === 'fight'){
                message.channel.send('Hmm...these guys do not stand a chance against fairies, psychics or flying types. Normal, ice, rock, dark and steel can easily submit though.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'ice'){
                message.channel.send('These icy Pokke are weak against steel, rock, fight and fire. But can do a bunch of damage to grass, ground, flying and dragon.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'grass'){
                message.channel.send('Let us cut this short, because I got places to be and people to meet. Grass are ineffective towards big, flying, poison, ice and fire, They are strong against water, ground and rock.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'electric'){
                message.channel.send('Ineffective towards ground but strong against water and flying...');
            }

            else if(commands === 'water'){
                message.channel.send('Water defeats fire, ground and rock! But they unfortunately have a weakness to grass and electic.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'fire'){
                message.channel.send('Rock, ground and water for weaknesses. Fortunately, they have strngths against grass, ice, bug and steel!');
            }

            else if(commands === 'normal'){
                message.channel.send('Their weakness is fight and they have no effects towards other types. Lame.');
            }

            else if(commands === 'all'){
                message.channel.send('Here you go! https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/792853588388872202/793211173062967306/image0.jpg?width=840&height=473');
            }
                message.channel.send(newEmbed);
                  }
          );
      }
}
```

And the main file has this code:(file directory: bot > index

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
  const client = new Discord.Client();

  var prefix = '%';
  const fs  = require('fs');

  client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

  const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
  for(const file of commandFiles){
      const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

      client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }

  client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('This bot is online!');
  });

  client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'effect'){
        client.commands.get('effect').execute(message, args);
    }   else if (command == 'pokedex'){
        client.commands.get('pokedex').execute(message, args);
    }

  });

  client.login('NzkzODk2MzA0OTE1Nzc1NDg4.X-y7jA.eVIwQXduvx7pVqHy3zAX_Qss1dE');
```

Comment: i regenerated my token so there wouldn't be any security issues. i totally forgot i had my token there

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong in this code

- You declared your prefix as `var prefix = '%';` so it would never respond to messages that start with "$"
- You are manually checking for command `if (command === 'effect') {` while this could be done dynamically
- Inside the file you are exporting you are adding another message event listener, you should only have one, do not ever add multiple of the same event listeners `client.on('message', message =>{`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

// Change the prefix
const prefix = "$";
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands/")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("This bot is online!");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }

  // Destructure the first word from message.content, leave the rest as an array
  const [commandName, ...args] = message.content
    .slice(prefix.length)
    .split(/ +/);

  // Attempt to get command by name from the Collection
  const command = client.commands.get(commandName.toLowerCase());

  if (!command) {
    return; // do something
  }

  command.execute(message, args);
});

client.login("INSERT TOKEN");
```

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "effect",
  description: "information on effects from pokke!",
  execute(message, args) {
    // args[0] would be the second word from message.content
    // You should check if they used the command the right way
    // $effect some-type would make args[0] some-type
    console.log(args[0]);
  },
};
```